# How to retrieve from Microsoft Graph all users that are members of all 3 groups from my list in a single request?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to retrieve from Microsoft Graph all users that are members of all 3 groups from my list. How can I do that in a single request?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `$filter` inside `$expand` of `memberOf` property on users' endpoint.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=memberOf($filter=id+eq+'{group1-id}' and id+eq+'{group2-id}' and id+eq+'{group3-id}')
```

But from my testing it looks like `$filter` is ignored, and all users are returned.

The second option

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=memberOf&$filter=memberOf/any(r:r/id eq '{group1-id}' and r/id+eq+'{group2-id}' and r/id+eq+'{group3-id}')&$count=true
```

with request header `ConsistencyLevel:eventual` returns

the error `Request_UnsupportedQuery` with the message `Multiple filter clauses are not supported on an 'Any' operation on a simple property`.

Currently, there is no functional way how retrieve all users that are members of all specified groups.